# AdvancedDataGrid Flex - Row not getting added under correct column

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, dynamic, datagrid, advanceddatagrid

I'm dynamically adding rows and they don't seem to go under the proper column. I have all of my headers in 'headerArray' and the data i need to add is in the string 'item'.

```
//create an item to work with
var chartItem:Object = new Object();
for( var j:int = 0; j < columnResult.length ; j++ ) 
{

    var item:String = removeformat(removetd(columnResult[j]));
    //grab the header (this is which column the value will be added
    var head:String = headerArray[j];
    //set the value to header (pair)
    chartItem[head] = item;
}
//add the chartItem (row) to the main collection
arr.addItem(chartItem);
tableCollection = arr;
```

It's getting all the headers properly and setting the chartItem (from inspection with debugger). When it gets to a row (building from html) where there is an item that only has values for some of the columns, it doesn't add the information under the right column, it just goes from left to right and adds it in the next one.

The behaviour is kind of strange because the chartItem clearly has the right header value and corresponding item value in it, but like I said they don't end up under the right column.

tableCollection gets set as the dataprovider for the grid later (not modified since)

Comment: looks like an off-by-one error, but this is hard to debug without more code to look at.  Any way you could paste more code? what do  your "removeFormat" and "removetd" functions do?

Comment: thanks for the comment, i think i solved it but i can't post the solution yet, i have to wait a few hours. i'll have it up so everyone can take a look. it involves grabbing the colspan attribute from the item im looking to add, then adding that colspan to all of the NEXT rows, effectively pushing them all over by that amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var chartItem:Object = new Object();
var span:int = 0;
for( var j:int = 0; j < columnResult.length ; j++ ) 
{
    var colSpan:int = this.getColSpan(columnResult[j]);         
    var item:String = removeformat(removetd(columnResult[j]));
    //grab the header (this is which column the value will be added
    var head:String;
    if (colSpan >1){
        head = headerArray[j];
        span = colSpan;
    } else {
        if (span == 0){
            head = headerArray[j];
        } else {
            head = headerArray[j+span-1]
        }
    }
    //set the value to header (pair)
    chartItem[head] = item;
}
//add the chartItem (row) to the main collection
arr.addItem(chartItem);
```

If i read the span attribute for the row, i set the NEXT row to be at column+previous colspan. then all the rows line up properly.